# Android setOnclick listner to listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Actually i have a viewpager that holds a Imageview and a listview over it, So when i click on the Listview i need to hide the listview and the bottom bar to make the ImageView fullscreen for all the views in side the viewpager. And onclick of the image view get back the views. But my issues are:

1. I cant implement onClickListner on Listview, to make the whole view to handle the tap. Am forced to use the onItemclickListner and it only hides when you click on the item(which is not desired).
2. When i click Listview(which is inside Fragment) inside the pager it doesn't hide for all the views except for the currentview, But am able to hide the actionbar and the bottom bar(on the Fragment Activity).

a screen shot for reference:

[image]

How can i achieve this or this is there any better way that i can hide the views.

Here is my ListView in side a Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my Fragment Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/edit_keyboard"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/send" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here am successful with the onitemclicklister to the ListView:

```
listComments.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    listComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    form.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                    listComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    form.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                listComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                form.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can Android know whether you click on an Item, or the ListView itself?

Comment: @tolgap Listview is ontop of the imageview and am implementing the onitemclicklistener inside the Fragment, so am able ot click on the list items

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the clickable property for the listView and check ? Also, whenever you add a new edittext to the do you add it dynamically ? If so that would mean that the you are adding items to the listView dynamically. The listView would not know if you have clicked on an item of the view itself hence a callback would get registered when you click the item as that takes preference.